# React Native Date Time Picker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-datepicker

I wanted to use a date time picker in React where I can view the time as Military time and not have an option for AM/PM and a sample code that can help me understand it. 
Thanks!

Comment: moment.js is a good place to start: https://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: You can use https://github.com/xgfe/react-native-datepicker for android there is a picker with Millitary time picker. For iOS you might be able to redesign the picker for your purpose but make sure you follow iOS guidelines https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/controls/pickers/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the 24 Hours rule on both iOS and Android and see that the is24Hour is not working on iOS, then you'll need to force the app to use en_GB as default DatePicker locale.

To do so, edit your AppDelegate.m file, and add [[UIDatePicker appearance] setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc]initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_GB"]]; to application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions